# simulating '<' operator in a c programme

Tags: c, shell, dup2

I am recreating a complete shell. For that I must simulate `<`. To do this, I have to use the function `dup2()`.

I made this but it didn't work and I donc't understand why :

```
void simple_redirection_left(char *buffer, int index, global *glob)
{
    char *file_name = &buffer[index + 1];
    int fd = 0;

    file_name = clean_file_name(file_name);
    if (file_name[0] == '\0') {
        my_putstr(1, "Missing name for redirect.\n");
        return;
    }

    if ((fd = open(file_name, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        printf("Error: file not found.\n");
        return;
    }

    dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
}
```

I first execute the binary on the left of the `<` in a `fork()` and then call the function above.

Did someone know why it didn't work ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Your title references `>`, your question references `<`, and your code is seemingly attempting `2>`. What are you actually trying to do? Please clarify the details of this question, and ideally post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You first set up `stdin`, `stdout` and/or `stderr` in the parent before `fork()`ing. Then you `fork()` and let the child execute with the inherited `stdin`, `stdout` and/or `stderr`. Reset (or whatever) the standard streams in the parent.

Comment: I made a mistake on the title, a have a probleme with le `<` operator. You say my code is attemping `2>`? I try to reproduce The behaviour of `<`.

Comment: Shells have more than one `<` operator -- in some contexts it's redirection, in other it's string or numeric comparison. It might help to make the title less ambiguous.

Comment: Anyhow, `<` redirects to fd 0, so it's unclear why your code is doing anything with fd 2 (STDERR_FILENO).

Comment: After you've redirected the input, you should close the original file descriptor.  That is for tidiness and to avoid running out of open file descriptors.

Comment: You say _"I first execute the binary on the left of the `<` in a `fork()` and then call the function above"_.  If you mean "the code above is called after `fork()` but before `exec*()`", then that is the correct sequence.  If you mean you try to call the function after using `exec*()`, then the sequence is incorrect.  Normally, "executing the binary" would mean "invoking `exec*()` to run the binary" — but that probably isn't what you mean.